# Can not add code to a repository in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

**Hey guys!**

I am trying to upload my project to our TFS server and then my intention is of course to build it...
The thing is: When I go to **Code->project_name** and I click on "Upload files" it only adds the files in the current folder. I know it can't be the case that I have to create tens of folders and then add the relevant files to it as shown in the original folder.

How do I do that without uploading all of the files? the build fails if I only upload a .sln file.
I am totally new to is so I really don't know how to use it...
I tried to do it via the VS but It gives me some weird errors.

Any help would be appreciated.
*Using TFS 2018.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TFVC, [map a workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/create-work-workspaces?view=vsts) on your machine and add the code there, then check it in.